# Why this formatted output is getting printed while using float?

Tags: c

In this underlying code:

```
   float j=9.01;
   printf("%2.3f \n",j);
```

the output is `9.010`, shouldn't it be like *2 character wide* reserved for the entire **j** which includes **3** for the decimal - so it makes the no. before decimal i.e. **9** disappear and only **01** to be printed?

Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: Read the documentation http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf Search the web there are tons of examples of how printf max field width and precision specifiers work. Experiment with different values to see for yourself. Being quick to jump to ask on SO it's just plain laziness.

Comment: @GradyPlayer I tried printing it using %5.3fh to see if 5 is for before the decimal and 3 after decimal but its not - 5 for the entire digits and 3 after the decimal.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus yeah I looked it up and removed my comment.

Comment: Who would have ever wanted to use a print function that prints `9.01` as `01`? Maybe this is hard to believe when you're coming to terms with some of the historical artifacts in C, but the designers weren't *intentionally* doing crazy things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's [quote the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> **Field Width**
>
> In no case does a nonexistent or small field width cause truncation of a field; if the result of a conversion is wider than the field width, the field is expanded to contain the conversion result.

and

> **The precision**
>
> This gives the minimum number of digits to appear for d, i, o, u, x, and X 
>   conversions, the number of digits to appear after the radix character for 
>   a, A, e, E, f, and F conversions [...]

The field width is too small, but fields are never truncated so that doesn't matter.

The part after the period is clearly the precision, and you ask for three digits.